# Bad gateway when submitting a POST request form with Zappa Flask app

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, aws-lambda, zappa

My flask app deployed to lambda and API Gateway using Zappa gives a Bad request error on form submission. This only happens when I map this app to my custom domain and the app runs without error locally and with the URL generated by API Gateway. I know most 400 errors are because of the backend asking for information not made available to by the front end(like incorrect input names). But such is not the case here. Has anyone ran into a similar trouble with maybe enabling CORS or some issue with CloudFront? Thanks

Comment: have you looked into all of the settings around the custom domain name?  did you add the custom domain entry to your DNS?  do you have an appropriate cert associated to your custom domain?

Comment: Yes. I doubled checked too